# 2by2 vs chisq.test functions

Tags: r

Probably a very basic stats question:

I've applied the 2by2 (from the epiR library) function with the chisq.test to the same 2x2 contingency table but I get different X-squared and p-values.

I use the 2by2 function as it gives me the OR and it's 95% CI, which  I don't see in the chisq.test result.  But I expect them to both give the same X-squared and p-values.

Why the difference?

The data:

Infection NoInfection

Yes         6          36

No         50        1326

The output from 2by2 function:

```
Point estimates and 95% CIs:
-------------------------------------------------------------------
Inc risk ratio                               3.93 (1.79, 8.66)
Odds ratio                                   4.42 (1.78, 10.97)
Attrib risk *                                10.65 (0.02, 21.28)
Attrib risk in population *                  0.32 (-1.10, 1.73)
Attrib fraction in exposed (%)               74.56 (44.00, 88.45)
Attrib fraction in population (%)            7.99 (-0.46, 15.73)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
 Test that odds ratio = 1: chi2(1) = 12.191 Pr>chi2 = < 0.001
 Wald confidence limits
 CI: confidence interval
 * Outcomes per 100 population units
```

The output from chisq.test function:

`X-squared = 9.5446, df = 1, p-value = 0.002005`

Comment: I'm guessing that `2by2` doesn't use the continuity correction that `chisq.test` uses be default.

Comment: I saw that yes, and when I use the correct=F parameter, the results are similar.  What is continuity correction for?